# How to avoid TypeError: callback.apply is not a function and Callback was already called ? node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I got   ++TypeError: callback.apply is not a function
and    ++Callback was already called.

this is my code:

```
var toFix = {
    'Mercedes': 'Mercedes-Benz'
  };

  var toUpdate = {
    'A-CLASSE': 'Classe A',
    'CLASSE A': 'Classe A',
  };

  async.series([

    function (cb) {
      console.log('Clean cars...');

      async.forEachOfSeries(toFix, function (to, from, cb) {
        console.log(`FixMakeForCars ${from} -> ${to}`);
        Car.update({'make': {$regex: S(from).trim().s, $options: 'i'}}, {$set: {'make': to}}, {multi: true}, cb);

      }, cb);

      async.forEachOfSeries(toUpdate, function (to, from, cb) {
        console.log(`UpdateModelForCars ${from} -> ${to}`);
        Car.update({'model': {$regex: S(from).trim().s, $options: 'i'}}, {$set: {'model': to}}, {multi: true}, cb);

      }, cb);

    },


    function (cb) {
      console.log('Clean car models...');

      async.forEachOfSeries(toFix, function (to, from, cb) {
        console.log(`FixCarModelMake ${from} -> ${to}`);
        CarModel.update(
          {'make': {$exists: true}}, {'model': {$exists: true}}, {'year': {$exists: true}},
          {'make': {$regex: S(from).trim().s, $options: 'i'}}, {$set: {'make': to}}, {multi: true}, cb);
      }, cb);

        async.forEachOfSeries(toUpdate, function (to, from, cb) {
          console.log(`UpdateModel ${from} -> ${to}`);
          CarModel.update(
            {'make':{ $exists: true}}, {'model':{ $exists: true}}, {'year':{ $exists: true}},
            {'car.model': {$regex: S(from).trim().s, $options: 'i'}}, {$set: {'car.model': to}}, {multi: true}, cb);
        }, cb);
    },


  ], function () {}
  );

};
```

this is carModel schema.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  make: {type: String, trim: true, required: true},
  model: {type: String, trim: true, required: true},
  year: {type: Number},
  enabled: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  range: {type: String, enum: _.values(Range)},
  premium: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  picture: {},
  status: {type: String, enum: _.values(CarModelStatus), default: CarModelStatus.DRAFT}
});

schema.index({model: 1, make: 1, year: 1}, {unique: true});
```

What should I do please?

and this the error in terminal:

[

```
2017-03-31T12:29:15.219Z] DEBUG: job/306 on f2a8df0485ee: FixCarModelMake Mercedes -> Mercedes-Benz (env=development)
    caller: {
      "line": "269",
      "pos": "17",
      "file": "job/apply-updates/3.8.1-update-to-Mercedes-Benz.js"
    }
[2017-03-31T12:29:15.237Z] ERROR: job/306 on f2a8df0485ee: (env=development)
    TypeError: callback.apply is not a function
        at /sources/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3411:16
```

thanks for helping me.

Comment: That error occurs when you try to call the apply method on a variable that is not a function.  It's difficult to troubleshoot without having access to the code since it's most likely an issue with what you are passing to the async module.  I would double check the async docs and make sure you are passing callback functions as parameters wherever required.  You will probably find there is a missing argument, or you are passing a non-function as an argument where a functions is required.

Comment: When you do `async.forEachOfSeries(…, cb)` twice, the `cb` will also be called twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of Errors in your code

1. There is mismatch of the query and update orders in `CarModel` update method, the mongoose `update` have 4 parameters

   `Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback)`
2. Inside One function in `.series` array you are performing two Other `async` function with callbacks, which will definitely throw an error

> `Callback was already Called`

Look at this Code Below and use

```
async.series([
    function (cb) {
        console.log('Clean cars...');
        // .eachOfSeries
        async.eachOfSeries(toFix, function (to, from, cb) {
            console.log(`FixMakeForCars ${from} -> ${to}`);
            Car.update({ 'make': { $regex: S(from).trim().s, $options: 'i' } }, { $set: { 'make': to } }, { multi: true }, function (err, res) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
                cb();
            });
        }, cb);
    },

    function (cb) {
        async.eachOfSeries(toUpdate, function (to, from, cb) {
            console.log(`UpdateModelForCars ${from} -> ${to}`);
            Car.update({ 'model': { $regex: S(from).trim().s, $options: 'i' } }, { $set: { 'model': to } }, { multi: true }, function (err, res) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
                cb()
            });
        }, cb);
    },

    function (cb) {
        console.log('Clean car models...');
        async.eachOfSeries(toFix, function (to, from, cb) {
            console.log(`FixCarModelMake ${from} -> ${to}`);
            // formed the valid query, no mismatch of orders
            let query = {
                'make': { $exists: true },
                'model': { $exists: true },
                'year': { $exists: true },
                'make': { $regex: S(from).trim().s, $options: 'i' }
            }
            CarModel.update(query, { $set: { 'make': to } }, { multi: true } , function (err, res) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
                cb()
            })
        }, cb);
    },

    function (cb) {
        async.eachOfSeries(toUpdate, function (to, from, cb) {
            console.log(`UpdateModel ${from} -> ${to}`);
             // formed the valid query, no mismatch of orders
            var query = {
                'make': { $exists: true },
                'model': { $exists: true },
                'year': { $exists: true },
                'model': { $regex: S(from).trim().s, $options: 'i' }
            }
            CarModel.update(query, { $set: { 'model': to } }, { multi: true } , function (err, res) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
                cb()
            })
        }, cb );
    }
  ], function () { 

  }
  );
```